# GoLang hangs in template indexing

Tags: templates, go, slice

I'm trying to fill in a table with the following template:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>Repo name</td>
        <td>Repo id</td>
    </tr>
    {{range $i, $e := .GitHubRepoNames}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{$e}}</td>
        <td>{{index .GitHubRepoNames $i}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{end}}
</table>
```

When I execute this template, it outputs:

```
<table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td>Repo name</td>
                <td>Repo id</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>https://api.github.com/repos/ertemplin/cah/issues{/number}</td>
                <td>
```

When I run the template without the {{index}} call:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>Repo name</td>
        <td>Repo id</td>
    </tr>
    {{range $i, $e := .GitHubRepoNames}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{$e}}</td>
        <td>{{$i}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{end}}
</table>
```

it outputs the complete range:

```
<table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td>Repo name</td>
                <td>Repo id</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>https://api.github.com/repos/ertemplin/cah/issues{/number}</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

What could be causing the output to be interrupted in the first instance of my template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you execute a template an error is returned:

```
var buf bytes.Buffer
err := tpl.Execute(&buf, map[string]interface{}{
    "GitHubRepoNames": []string{
        "https://api.github.com/repos/ertemplin/cah/issues{/number}",
    },
})
fmt.Println(err, buf.String())
```

The error is:

> template: ex:9:20: executing "ex" at <.GitHubRepoNames>: can't evaluate field GitHubRepoNames in type string

Which means the `.` is being changed to `$e`. I'm not sure why you need to do the index like this (`$e` seems like it ought to be sufficient) but you can do this:

```
<td>{{index $.GitHubRepoNames $i}}</td>
```

`$` is explained by the documentation:

> When execution begins, $ is set to the data argument passed to Execute, that is, to the starting value of dot.

Comment: I was using the index to access something in another array instead of making a tuple struct. Thanks for the answer!